# Got Unsafe usage of ThrowStatement (no-unsafe-finally) in my Firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

It's been a while since I've changed to my Flutter Firebase functions code.

And today, I am blocked from deploying the new code because I get this error:

> 7:497  error  Unsafe usage of ThrowStatement                             no-unsafe-finally

And over 120 of the likes in my code (such as `Expected a 'break' statement before 'case'` etc.).

By inspecting the code generated as follows:

```js
function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { if (!(Symbol.iterator in Object(arr) || Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === "[object Arguments]")) { return; } var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }
```

I understand that `eslint` sees the `throw` in the `finally` is the source of the issue it reports.

As I am using version 11.18.0 and that 12.4.5 is available, I wonder if this error would be fixed and whether upgrading could draw me into additional or others issues.

So, maybe I could start with a fix in `eslintrc.js` or you think is safe to go to `npm install -g firebase-tools`?

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting here? Why don't you just give these things that you're proposing a try?

Comment: Benefiting from someone else's experience would prevent me from getting into more trouble

Comment: But what sort of answer are you expecting? "This is OK?"  Seems to me you could just give it a try and know for yourself.  You don't have to commit anything to source control.  Are you sure maybe you aren't actually just trying to start a general conversation that would be more suited for a site like Reddit?